# Exponential curve fitting in SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have two NumPy arrays `x` and `y`. When I try to fit my data using exponential function and `curve_fit` (SciPy) with this simple code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.array([399.75, 989.25, 1578.75, 2168.25, 2757.75, 3347.25, 3936.75, 4526.25, 5115.75, 5705.25])
y = np.array([109,62,39,13,10,4,2,0,1,2])

def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(b-c*x)+d

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
```

I get wrong coefficients `popt`

```
[a,b,c,d] = [1., 1., 1., 24.19999988]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527869/curve-fit-fails-with-exponential-but-zunzun-gets-it-right

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First comment: since `a*exp(b - c*x) = (a*exp(b))*exp(-c*x) = A*exp(-c*x)`, `a` or `b` is redundant.  I'll drop `b` and use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x, a, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(-c*x)+d
```

That isn't the main issue.  The problem is simply that `curve_fit` fails to converge to a solution to this problem when you use the default initial guess (which is all 1s).  Check `pcov`; you'll see that it is `inf`.  This is not surprising, because if `c` is 1, most of the values of `exp(-c*x)` underflow to 0:

```
In [32]: np.exp(-x)
Out[32]: 
array([  2.45912644e-174,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,
         0.00000000e+000])
```

This suggests that `c` should be small. A better initial guess is, say, `p0 = (1, 1e-6, 1)`.  Then I get:

```
In [36]: popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=(1, 1e-6, 1))

In [37]: popt
Out[37]: array([  1.63561656e+02,   9.71142196e-04,  -1.16854450e+00])
```

This looks reasonable:

```
In [42]: xx = np.linspace(300, 6000, 1000)

In [43]: yy = func(xx, *popt)

In [44]: plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')
Out[44]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x41c5ad0>]

In [45]: plt.plot(xx, yy)
Out[45]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x41c5c10>]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use -c instead of c? curve_fit can find a negative c if necessary, no?

Comment: @RenéG: That's the convention that drastega used in the question.

Comment: Another approach to initial parameters (using default values, that is) is normalizing _x_ to (approximately) 0—1, e.g., _ξ=x/k_, estimate _a_, _c'_ and _d_ and eventually have _c=c'/k_.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly I would recommend modifying your equation to `a*np.exp(-c*(x-b))+d`, otherwise the exponential will always be centered on `x=0` which may not always be the case.
You also need to specify reasonable initial conditions (the 4th argument to `curve_fit` specifies initial conditions for `[a,b,c,d]`).

This code fits nicely:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.array([399.75, 989.25, 1578.75, 2168.25, 2757.75, 3347.25, 3936.75, 4526.25, 5115.75, 5705.25])
y = np.array([109,62,39,13,10,4,2,0,1,2])

def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(-c*(x-b))+d

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, [100,400,0.001,0])
print popt

plot(x,y)
x=linspace(400,6000,10000)
plot(x,func(x,*popt))
show()
```

Comment: Where do initial conditions come from?

Comment: @MarcinZdunek this was a while ago so I don't remember exactly. The amplitude will have been estimated from the graph. The others may have been determined via trial and error, although the value for c can be estimated too (see the accepted answer of this question)

Comment: @MarcinZdunek The default initial values are fine if you normalize both data ranges and afterwards denormalize the estimated parameters...

Comment: I'll just add that looking over this again, I think the initial conditions for `a` and `b` came from the first `y` and `x` values (assuming values are in order), `c` can be estimated as in the accepted answer, and the estimate for `d` came from the final `y` values which are `~0`. If you're having trouble with initial conditions, this can be a good starting point.